# Google Oauth2 Bearer token as session id

Tags: session, google-authentication

I have implemented google-signin using the oauth2 from Angular Application.
Once authentication is successful and the token is generated, I am storing it in the LocalStorage/IndexedDB and also trying to send this Token, UserProfile info etc, to my flask-backend.
I would validate the token and continue the flow
Now, I want to use the user bearer token as my Session-ID, i.e, each API call I am doing, I will be doing by validating against this bearer token.

I believe by doing so, I will be able to avoid 'creating sessions' and also leverage the google-generated tokens for uniquely identifying users and the calls to backend.

Please let me know what security flaws this would give rise to and also what are the alternatives for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although at the point of time I was making the question, it was a bit unclear on how to proceed, heres a summary of what I have accomplished -

1 - I have used Angular for frontend and I have [refered this page](https://w3path.com/angular-8-social-login-with-example/)
2 - While doing so, my doubt was how would I proceed with  user authentication and how I would continue to register the user and get the required details like profile, contact, address etc.

What I have done ->
Once a bearer was issued, I was passing this info to backend and then, from the backend, I was reaching out to various google api's and getting relevant info with the bearer.

Also this bearer was being stored on client end so as to ensure UNTIL the token expires, I would continue to not issue another token and meanwhile, as and when the user session times out, I would read the locally stored(client side) token and validate it on backend,

should the token be valid, backend server would go and all the info for all the scopes, and deal the other flows accordingly.